# Open University Physics Department and Master's Degree in EU

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, physics

I would like to ask if anyone here has finished the UK Open University's degree in Physics and has successfully applied for a master's degree.
With this question, I want to make sure that by applying for this degree will allow me to further advance my studies. Ideally in a Swiss university.
Additionally, is this Open University degree suitable for a job in academia?

Comment: No undergraduate degree is enough for a faculty position. That would depend, usually, on obtaining a doctorate.

Comment: I am always skeptical with "is it possible?" questions, because the answer is almost always "Yes, at least if you are exceptional," and that's usually not a very useful answer.  Please try to indicate what kind of likelihood/ordinariness you're looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently 60 credits from completing my OU maths degree which I've thoroughly enjoyed. I have also done computational research prior to starting with the OU.
There are several OU students who have been accepted onto masters degrees at top Universities. I know a student who is now completing her masters at Oxford University in computer science having completed an OU BSc in maths and computer science with first class. I know other folks who have gone onto PhDs at brick and mortar universities following OU degrees.
I'm planning to undertake a masters after my OU degree at a brick university just for more exposure and variety.
The physics degree at the OU shares a number of modules in common with the maths degree (mathematical methods, fluid mechanics and PDEs, quantum mechanics, etc).
In summary, an OU degree is just as respected as any other degree. If you want more inspiration and are on facebook, do join the Open University facebook groups.
I'm not sure whether Swiss universities are familiar with OU degrees-worth checking this. I don't see any reason why OU degrees won't be suitable for securing jobs in academia. However, academic jobs are very competitive and research experience with PhD is usually necessary.
Best wishes with your studies.

Comment: I have a similar understanding of the quality of programs at OU, and have worked with some of their faculty and administrators in the past. It was in CS, however.